# Why doesn't setting GIT_WORK_TREE work in a post-commit hook?

Tags: git, githooks, git-checkout

I'm trying to use the following `post-commit` hook to deploy to a particular directory after each successful commit:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/example/
export GIT_DIR=/home/mark/test/.git/
git checkout -f
```

However, after committing I get the following error:

```
$ git commit -m 'An example commit.'
fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/example/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
[master 0938e48] An example commit.
```

... as if the `GIT_WORK_TREE` setting is being ignored.  Why does setting this environment variable appear to be not working?  I'm using git version 1.7.4.1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is that in `post-commit` hooks (and also
`pre-commit`, `prepare-commit-msg` and `commit-msgt`) the
`GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable is set to `.git/index`.  (This
isn't documented in the [githooks
documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html), but I've
posted elsewhere [about the settings of environment variables and the
current directory in git
hooks](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/).)

The effect of the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable is described
in the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES section of the `git` man page as:

> **GIT_INDEX_FILE**
>
> This environment [variable] allows the specification of an alternate index file. If not specified, the default of `$GIT_DIR/index` is used.

... and for some reason, in this situation, `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is being
used relative to `GIT_WORK_TREE`.

To make the hook work as you would expect, you just need to unset
`GIT_INDEX_FILE`, so your hook would look like:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
 export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/example/
 export GIT_DIR=/home/mark/test/.git/
 git checkout -f
```

Comment: could this also be used to make the worktree and gitdir options work on git stash and other commands? `git --worktree --gitdir <some command>` seems to only work on certain commands.

Comment: @Adam Dymitruk: I've found that `--work-tree=DIRECTORY` and `--git-dir=DIRECTORY` work reliably outside hooks regardless of the command, so long as I (a) set them both, and (b) set them both to absolute paths, just in order to avoid having to remember the confusing rules about how the eventual work tree and repository directory are calculated...

Comment: this is outside a hook altogether. some work, some don't.. I'll have to confirm whether some of them don't work because of relative paths.. But it would be odd for that kind of behaviour as I'm using the same path and just changing the command.

Comment: @Adam Dymitruk: Indeed - it would be interesting to see an example.