# Git Post Receive Hook: update current working branch to staging server

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

So, I have a staging server setup, and what I would like to do is when someone pushes to a non master branch update what the staging server's directory. My current post-receive hook looks like:

```
echo "post hook is on the run!"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    echo "$ref"
done

unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
cd ../staging/bikereport
git fetch
git pull origin $ref

echo "Post receive finsihed"
```

However I am not seeing the changes I would like on the server, and remote returns "Already up-to-date" which makes me think it's pulling from Master or something?

This isn't an elegant solution, but we are a *very* small team working on a single project. An ideal solution would be to save every branch to a new directory within the staging server and then update only that directory per push.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ../staging/bikereport
git fetch
```

Beware: your git directory is **not** your `staging/bikereport` repo.
It is *still* the one where the hook is running.

You need to set `GIT_DIR` to `/full/path/ofstaging/bikereport/.git` (and to be sure, set `GIT_WORK_TREE` to `/full/path/ofstaging/bikereport`) in order for commands run from *that* repo to work.
*And* you need to unset `GIT_INDEX_FILE`!

See "[Why doesn't setting GIT_WORK_TREE work in a post-commit hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645492/6309)" for more details.

You hook should start with:

```
#!/bin/sh
 unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
 export GIT_WORK_TREE=/full/path/ofstaging/bikereport/
 export GIT_DIR=/full/path/ofstaging/bikereport/.git/
```