# source code not pushed to git server via ssh from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

Using Eclipse, I try to push git repository to Git server after making changes in a java file & commit via ssh.

Problem: Only the commit info are pushed to Git server but not the actual java source code.
How can I push java code to Git server from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [Egit tutorial on committing changes](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Committing_Changes), make sure you have added the source code which just changed, before committing.

If you don't select `Team > Add`, the commit won't include those changes.

You must see files in the stages changes part of the commit dialog:

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/f/ff/Egit-3.1-StagingView.png]

> Alternatively you may display untracked files in the Commit dialog and check the Show untracked Files checkbox to select them for inclusion into the commit.

---

As for a post-receive hook, it is best if you set `GIT_DIR` in addition of `GIT_WORK_TRE`. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645492/6309):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
 export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/example/
 export GIT_DIR=/home/mark/test/.git/
 git checkout -f
```

Comment: i tried this steps before & also create a post-receive hook on git server which contains the following

"##!/bin/sh
#GIT_WORK_TREE=/shero/src git checkout -f"

but nothing happens inside shero/src folder

Comment: @MurtazaLokhandwala First, check with a `git log -p` that you do see the changes in the bare repo to which you just push. Then we can think about debugging your hook.

Comment: yes the changes are shown in git bash i just pushed

Comment: @MurtazaLokhandwala So, on the server side, you do confirm the changes are there?

Comment: @MurtazaLokhandwala Does the hook I mention works better? (replace the path by your own paths)

Comment: yes it works & the code successfully pushed. Thanks for your answers. Appreciate you for this :)

Comment: @MurtazaLokhandwala Great, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer