# Git post-commit hook on Windows results in ".git/index.lock: No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, git, githooks

I want to copy my work tree to a different location after each commit on Windows. I added a post-commit hook with following contents:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# the work tree, where the checkout/deploy should happen
TARGET="C:\Users\...\copy"

# the location of the .git directory
GIT_DIR="C:\Users\...\repo\.git"

BRANCH="master"

echo "Do something"
git --work-tree="${TARGET}" --git-dir="${GIT_DIR}" checkout -f ${BRANCH}
```

When doing a git commit from command line it results in following output:

```
warning: in the working copy of 'test.html', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
Do something
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/.../copy/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
[master c68d639] asdasd
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Executing the script manually from command line works just fine and copies the work tree just as requested.

```
MINGW64 ~/.../repo/.git/hooks (GIT_DIR!)
$ ./post-commit
Do something
Already on 'master'
```

After the manual execution of this script there is no `.git` directory in the end result directory either as it should be. So why does the automatic execution not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645492/6309), you need to unset [`GIT_INDEX_FILE`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations)

> `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is the path to the index file (non-bare repositories only).

In general, in a hook, I try and `unset GIT_xxx` variable I do not need (or that I specify explicitly as your did with `--work-tree` and `--git-dir`).