# How can I write a commit hook to cherry-pick last commit from main branch to other worktrees in a bare repo?

Tags: git, githooks, git-bare, git-worktree

I have 3 branches called `main`, `macos` and `linux`. As soon as I commit something to `main` branch, I want to cherry-pick that commit to other two branches. I also want to do this in a bare repo.

```bash
❯ git clone --bare <bare-repo-url>
❯ cd my-bare-repo
❯ git worktree add main
❯ git worktree add linux
❯ git worktree add macos
❯ cd main
❯ touch README.md
❯ git add README.md
❯ git commit -m "Add README" # <- this commit should be cherry picked to the other two branches
```

Actually, if I write the following 2 commands in shell, I can manually do that:

```
❯ git --git-dir=<path-to-bare-repo>/worktrees/linux --work-tree=<path-to-bare-repo>/linux cherry-pick main
❯ git --git-dir=<path-to-bare-repo>/worktrees/macos --work-tree=<path-to-bare-repo>/macos cherry-pick main
```

But when I write a `post-commit` hook for this job, somehow it doesn't work as expected. It is working like as if I didn't provided `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options and try to cherry-pick from the same branch and conflict happens. How can I fix this script?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)

# Check if committing to the main branch
if [ "$current_branch" = "main" ]; then
    gitdir=$(dirname `pwd`)
    # Update the linux branch
    git --git-dir="$gitdir/worktrees/linux" --work-tree="$gitdir/linux" cherry-pick main

    # Update the macos branch
    git --git-dir="$gitdir/worktrees/macos" --work-tree="$gitdir/macos" cherry-pick main

fi
```

```
❯ git commit -m "Add README"
error: your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
error: your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
[main ed96ee9] Add README
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README
```

I also tried `cd ../linux; git cherry-pick main` but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645492/9608759). The problem is fixed after adding `unset GIT_INDEX_FILE` to the script.

```bash
...
gitdir=$(dirname `pwd`)
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
...
```

Quoting the original answer directly:

> The problem here is that in `post-commit` hooks (and also
> `pre-commit`, `prepare-commit-msg` and `commit-msgt`) the
> `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable is set to `.git/index`.  (This
> isn't documented in the [githooks
> documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html), but I've
> posted elsewhere [about the settings of environment variables and the
> current directory in git
> hooks](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/).)
>
> The effect of the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable is described
> in the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES section of the `git` man page as:
>
> > **GIT_INDEX_FILE**
> >
> > This environment [variable] allows the specification of an alternate index file. If not specified, the default of `$GIT_DIR/index` is used.
>
> ... and for some reason, in this situation, `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is being
> used relative to `GIT_WORK_TREE`.
>
> To make the hook work as you would expect, you just need to unset
> `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, so your hook would look like:
>
> ```
>  #!/bin/sh
>  unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
>  export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/example/
>  export GIT_DIR=/home/mark/test/.git/
>  git checkout -f
> ```